# "No viable alternative at input" error for ANTLR 4 JSON grammar

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4

I am trying to adapt the STRING part of Pair in Object to a CamelString, but it fails. and report "No viable alternative at input".

I have tried to used my CamelString as an independent grammar, it works well. I think it means there is ambiguity in my grammar, but I can not understand why.

For the test input

```
{
   'BaaaBcccCdddd':'cc'
}
```

Ther error is

```
line 2:2 no viable alternative at input '{'BaaaBcccCdddd''
```

The following is my grammar. It's almost the same with the standard JSON grammar for ANTLR 4.

```
/** Taken from "The Definitive ANTLR 4 Reference" by Terence Parr */

// Derived from http://json.org

grammar Json;


json:   object
    |   array
    ;

object
    :   '{' pair (',' pair)* '}'
    |   '{' '}' // empty object
    ;

pair : camel_string ':' value;

camel_string : '\'' (camel_body)*? '\'';

STRING
    : '\'' (ESC | ~['\\])* '\'';

camel_body: CAMEL_BODY;

CAMEL_START: [a-z] ALPHA_NUM_LOWER*;
CAMEL_BODY: [A-Z] ALPHA_NUM_LOWER*;
CAMEL_END: [A-Z]+;

fragment ALPHA_NUM_LOWER : [0-9a-z];

array
    :   '[' value (',' value)* ']'
    |   '[' ']' // empty array
    ;



value
    :   STRING
    |   NUMBER
    |   object  // recursion
    |   array   // recursion
    |   'true'  // keywords
    |   'false'
    |   'null'
    ;

fragment ESC :   '\\' (["\\/bfnrt] | UNICODE) ;
fragment UNICODE : 'u' HEX HEX HEX HEX ;
fragment HEX : [0-9a-fA-F] ;
NUMBER
    :   '-'? INT '.' [0-9]+ EXP? // 1.35, 1.35E-9, 0.3, -4.5
    |   '-'? INT EXP             // 1e10 -3e4
    |   '-'? INT                 // -3, 45
    ;

fragment INT :   '0' | [1-9] [0-9]* ; // no leading zeros
fragment EXP :   [Ee] [+\-]? INT ; // \- since - means "range" inside [...]
WS  :   [ \t\n\r]+ -> skip ;
```

Comment: Caveat: I am not an ANTLR user, but to me it seems that your definition chain `camel_body -> CAMEL_BODY -> [A-Z] ALPHA_NUM_LOWER* -> [0-9a-z]` only allows upper-case characters in the first position and your sample input does not comply with that.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError, thanks for your reply.  `camel_string : '\'' (camel_body)*? '\'';` means the body will repeat many times, so I can have multiple `camel_body` in one `camel_string`.

Comment: Oh, right - incidentally, isn't the `?` redundant there?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError, that's one of the ANTLR black magics. Adding an extra ? means non-greedy matching. It might not be necessary, I'm just trying out possible solutions in the grammar.

Comment: Ah, I see - good to know.